# Error in function to display images from Landsat 5

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-5

I have created a function that suppose to take images (which stored in a list) and display them, but I get all the time the next error:

```
Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): function standin(_0) {
       return newF.apply(this, arguments);   }
```

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('1985-01-01', '2012-04-30')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};


//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});

var RGBlist=clippedCol.toList(clippedCol.size());
for(var i in RGBlist){
  var imageRGB=ee.Image(RGBlist.get(RGBlist[i]));
  Map.addLayer(imageRGB,visParams,'i');
}
```

My end goal is to display all the images from the given date range in RGB colors, and to give each image a name automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work?

You could improve the naming of your plot function I gues..

```
    /**
 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 */
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  // or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
                  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
                  .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3));
  // Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterDate('1985-01-01', '2012-04-30')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(cloudMaskL457);

var visParams = {
  bands: ['B3', 'B2', 'B1'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};


//clip the dataset according to the geometry
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
});


var RGBlist=clippedCol.toList(clippedCol.size());
print(RGBlist, 'RGBlist')
var count = RGBlist.size(); 
print(count, 'count')

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"],"min":-468,"max":1228,"gamma":1};

ee.List.sequence(0,ee.Number(count.subtract(1))).getInfo()
.map(function(img){
  // print(img)

  var image = ee.Image(RGBlist.get(img))

  Map.addLayer(image, imageVisParam, img.toString())
})
```